# PHP Update script.. filemtime?

Tags: php

I am sort of a beginner to PHP and am trying to make a script that shows, in a file which I can include on the side part of my index page, the date of a last update and plus underneath that a list of which other pages I have updated (in order of update). So for an example if the last time I updated was Tuesday and I only edited my news and index page it would say

August 6, 2013
- Home Page Updated.
- News Headlines Updated.

Then underneath it would show the other latest updates.. like so:

August 6, 2013
- Home Page Updated.
- News Headlines Updated.

August 5, 2013
- Staff Updated.

August 2, 2013
- Home Page Updated.
- Forum Updated.
- Join Page Updated.

I would also like to be able to set a limit on how many updates can be shown.. I had a friend who had this script years ago and I remember he done it through a .txt file and CHMOD the txt file to have written permissions. Then their was updates.php and on every page I wanted to generate an update status I would include a few lines of some scripting at the top of the file.. Plus I would list the page names and what I wanted it to show in either the txt file or updates file like index.php > Home Page Updated... However I have lost contact with him and their is no way of me finding it. I had a go and and got:

```
  <?php

  $pages = array(
  'Main Page' => 'index3.php',
  'Staff' => 'staff.php',
  'News Headlines' => 'news.php',
  );
$list = array();

 foreach($pages as $page => $file) {
  $date = filemtime($file);    
 if(!isset($list[$date])) { $list[$date] = array(); }
  array_push($list[$date], $page);
  }
 krsort($list);

 foreach($list as $date => $pages) {
  echo date('F j, Y', $date) . "<br />\n";
   foreach($pages as $page) {
    echo "- $page Updated<br />\n";
    }
      }
   ?>
```

But this doesn't work correctly as it starts a new date even if I update two files in the same day... Anyway I was just wondering if anybody had any idea of how to make this script? I am in desperate need to get it so any help would be great.. I am really unsure of how to go about it and have looked everywhere for ages for ideas... Thanks people and I hope to hear something back :)

Answer (score 0):

filemtime() will return a Unix timestamp, so two updates in the same day will still be two different timestamps.  Instead of only using date() to format the date when you echo it, format it before saving it to the $date variable:

```
foreach($pages as $page => $file) {
  $date = date('Y/m/d', filemtime($file));
```

Then when you print it out:

```
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($date)) . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't necessarily have to use filemtime(), I just thought that because it seemed appropriate to use but I don't want the time to show anyway just the date with a list of files that were modified in that day but going by names I give, not their file names.. My bad maybe I should of left the whole filemtime() thing out.. Anyway I am going to try out what you said, thanks!

Comment: Kodepup thanks a lot for your reply..I'm still having a few problems,I have an update from July 31 and that seems to stay as the top update where as I want it to be generated in order of date. Also when I update a file say a day after my last update, it removes the update from the days before date and adds it to the new date...

Comment: Oops, I forgot to account for your wanting to sort by date.  I updated the code snippets in my answer.  Since `date()` will return the date as a string, it also sorts as a string.  By formatting it in a way that can be sorted chronologically even as a string, you can get them in order, then just reformat for display.

Comment: I'm still having the problem where if I update the same file day after day it takes that file out of the update from the day before and places it under the new date, I do want it to place it under the new date it was modified but also stay under the other dates it was.. Plus when I add a news article from online forms (admin section) it doesn't generate an update. Maybe attempting to use MySQL and php would be more sufficient? Or is their still a way by changing the current script I have? Thanks again for your help kodepup.

Comment: If you don't want to show only the most recent modification of a file, `filemtime()` won't be enough.  You could either keep a change log file that you could read in for display, or you could track changes in a database. If you're comfortable using cron jobs, you can modify the existing code and call it once a day to take all updates from only the current day and save them in either place.  If not, I'd say just manually update a log file any time you make changes, use that for display.